# How to write this Python code to remove duplicate values Java?

Tags: python, hashmap

Could someone help me to write this code in Java? I am still a beginner and came across a course about algorithms in Lynda.com. However, the course was based on python. Any help is much appreciated.

```py
# using a hashtable to count individual items

# define a set of items that we want to count
items = ["apple", "pear", "orange", "banana", "apple",
         "orange", "apple", "pear", "banana", "orange",
         "apple", "kiwi", "pear", "apple", "orange"]

# create a hashtable object to hold the items and counts
counter = dict()

# iterate over each item and increment the count for each one
for item in items:
    if item in counter.keys():
        counter[item] += 1
    else:
        counter[item] = 1

# print the results
print(counter)
```

Comment: Have you tried translating it to Java by yourself?

Comment: This is not a code conversion site. But these may help:`items` is a `List`, `counter` is a `Map`, and I hope you already know about `for`, `if else` and `print` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to explain you the java code as simple as possible, and converted it 1 to 1:

```
String[] fruits = {"apple", "pear", "orange", "banana", "apple",
         "orange", "apple", "pear", "banana", "orange",
         "apple", "kiwi", "pear", "apple", "orange"};
```

This is just the Array of fruits. `String` represents the datatype, the [] defines an array of it.

```
HashMap<String,Integer> counter = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

`HashMap` is a mapping datatype, like `dict` in python. In the <> brackets, the two datatypes are defined `HashMap<Key, Value>`.

Now, a foreach loop over all strings from the Array:

```
for(String fruit: fruits){
    if(!counter.containsKey(fruit)) //If counter map does not contain the fruit yet
        counter.put(fruit, 1); //add it
    else 
        counter.put(fruit,counter.get(fruit) + 1); // else count one up
}
```

Now just print the output:

```
System.out.println(counter); //{orange=4, banana=2, apple=5, pear=3, kiwi=1}
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work (not tested)

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList("apple", "pear", "orange", "banana", "apple", "orange", "apple", "pear", "banana", "orange", "apple",
    "kiwi", "pear", "apple", "orange");

// solution 1
HashMap<String, Integer> itemToCountMap1 = new HashMap<>();
for (String item : items) {
  Integer currentValue = itemToCountMap1.get(item);
  if (currentValue == null) { // currently not in the map
    itemToCountMap1.put(item, 1);
  } else { //was already in the map
    itemToCountMap1.put(item, currentValue + 1);
  }
}

// solution 2
Map<String, Long> itemToCountMap2 = items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()));
```